# Insert SQL data into table in ASP.Net Web Application via textbox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2017

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace todoassignment1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Visible = false;  
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string valueUser = txtUsername.Text;

            SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //User is the name of the table, UserName is the column 
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT User (UserName) VALUES ('" + valueUser + "')";

            cmd.Connection = db;

            db.Open();

            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Label1.Text = "Success writing into database!";
                Label1.Visible = true;  
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Error writing into database.";
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Label1.Visible = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                db.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added the SqlDataSource1 on the Default.aspx page, which seems to be done successfully as I can see the column names of the User table in the gridview. The table is empty, and all I'm trying to do is take input in a textbox and send it to the UserName column.
I'm not very good at debugging, but I have noticed a few errors which I have spent hours researching.
Things I've tried:

- SQL SMS > tools > options > designers > CHECK prevent saving  changes that require table re-creation
- Added using System.Data;
- Added cmd.Connection.Open();
- Added an exception to be caught in the catch statement
- Recreate entire database
- Quadruple checked things like txtUsername being the correct textbox ID
- Reconfigure SqlDataSource1 over and over, delete and recreate
- Confirm that the connectionString in web.config is correct
- Create the new SQLConnection with the exact string in web.config

  ```
      SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NAME-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Assignment;Integrated Security=True");
  ```
- Changed the insert line from concatenation to just "INSERT User (UserName) VALUES ('asdf')" to simplify code, still doesn't work.
- Tried other syntax

  ```
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User (UserName) VALUES (@username)";

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

      cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = txtUsername.Text.ToString();
  ```

Clues from the debugger:

- saw several "System.InvalidCastExceptions when digging through cmd in autos
- **errorCS0103: the name 'ExecuteNonQuery' does not exist in the current context**
- Always see **System.InvalidOperationException** after running

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string valueUser = "test"; //txtUsername.Text;
    using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"))//SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString);
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.[User] (UserName) VALUES (@valueUser)", db);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@valueUser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = valueUser;
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //User is the name of the table, UserName is the column 
        //cmd.CommandText = "INSERT User (UserName) VALUES (@valueUser)";

        //cmd.Connection = db;

        db.Open();

        try
        {
            //cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            /*Label1.Text =*/
            Console.WriteLine("Success writing into database!");
            //Label1.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /*Label1.Text =*/
            Console.WriteLine("Error writing into database.");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //Label1.Visible = true;
        }
        //finally
        //{
            //db.Close();
        //}
    }
}
```

A couple of issues.

1. The syntax for insert is `INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMNS) VALUES (VALUES)` You had "INSERT User (UserName)"...
2. `USER` is a reserved word in SQL. If you insist upon using it as your table name it must be wrapped in square brackets.
3. You were opening the connection twice.  Not really a problem per se, but unnecessary.
4. Always, always, always be using parameters.
5. I simplified things a little.

If you modify the method I've attached you should be able to copy paste it.

Comment: I think it was the second issue, as I had already tried the first suggestion. I created a new table that was named Person instead of User, modified it slightly to get the email as well, and it finally took my input. Thank you so much!

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s Understood. I don't bother writing queries like that anymore and mostly use Dapper these days. Thank you for the link, I'll give it a read.